# Is there a python library for Anviz vf30 trugh tcp/ip?

Tags: python, tcpclient

I want to retrieve records with queries from the device using tcp/ip commands. I tried to test this

```
import socket
import struct

# Function to construct a command message
def construct_command(device_code, command):
    stx = 0xA5
    len_data = 0x000A
    crc16 = 0x0000
    return struct.pack('>B4sBBHH', stx, device_code, command, len_data, 0, crc16)

# Function to parse a response message
def parse_response(response):
    stx, device_code, ack, ret, len_data, data, crc16 = struct.unpack('>B4sBBHH16sH', response)
    return stx, device_code, ack, ret, len_data, data, crc16

HOST = '172.16.10.36'  # Replace with the IP address of your Anviz VF30
PORT = 5010             # Default port for Anviz devices

try:
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((HOST, PORT))
        print("Connection initiated")
        
        # Ensure the command is correctly constructed
        device_code = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        command = 0x03
        command_message = construct_command(device_code, command)
        
        # Send the command
        s.sendall(command_message)
        print('Command sent')
        
        # Receive and process the response
        response = b""
        while True:
            chunk = s.recv(1024)
            if not chunk:
                break
            response += chunk
        print(f"Received: {response}")

        # Parse the response
        parsed_response = parse_response(response)
        print("Parsed Response:", parsed_response)
        
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

I want a library in which I can use the class to send commands and formatted the response to be inserted in mysql database. Please help